# Run nuxt on https locally – problem with nuxt.config.js

Tags: vue.js, https, server, nuxt.js

I am trying to run nuxt locally with https to test some geolocation stuff.
(https://nuxtjs.org/, https://nuxtjs.org/api/nuxt)

I was following this tutorial:
https://www.mattshull.com/blog/https-on-localhost

And then I found this:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/146

Both links seem to describe pretty nicely how to run nuxt with server.js programmatically.

The thing is that in my nuxt.config.js I seem to have some problems.
I get the following error when runnung `yarn dev`:

```
/Users/USER/Documents/github/mynuxtrepo/nuxt.config.js:2
import { module } from 'npmmodule'

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

In my nuxt config I import a custom helper to generate localized routes. Not really important what it does but obviously it can't handle the import syntax.
I assume that the node version does not understand.

So how can I get it to run? Do I have to require everything instead of importing?
Or is my assumption wrong and the cause lies somewhere totally different?

Thank you for your help
Cheers.

**------
Edit 1:**
My nuxt config looks like this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
import { generateLocalizedRoutes, generateRoutesFromData } from 'vuecid-helpers'
import config from './config'

// TODO: Add your post types
const postTypes = [{ type: 'pages' }, { type: 'posts', paginated: true }]

// TODO: Add your site title
const siteTitle = 'Title'
const shortTitle = 'short title'
const siteDescription = 'Page demonstrated with a wonderful example'
const themeColor = '#ffffff'
// TODO: Replace favicon source file in /static/icon.png (512px x 512px)
// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
const iconSizes = [32, 57, 60, 72, 76, 144, 120, 144, 152, 167, 180, 192, 512]

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: 'Loading…',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: config.env.DEFAULTLANG,
      dir: 'ltr' // define directionality of text globally
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },

      // TODO: Check this info
      { name: 'author', content: 'Author' },
      { name: 'theme-color', content: themeColor },

      // TODO: Add or remove google-site-verification
      {
        name: 'google-site-verification',
        content: '...W1GdU'
      }
    ],
    link: []
  },

  /*
  ** env: lets you create environment variables that will be shared for the client and server-side.
  */
  env: config.env,

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  ** TODO: Set your desired loading bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#0000ff' },

  /*
  ** CSS
  */
  css: ['@/assets/css/main.scss'],

  /*
  ** Plugins
  */
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/global.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/throwNuxtError.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/axios' },
    { src: '~/plugins/whatinput.js', ssr: false },
    { src: '~/plugins/i18n.js', injectAs: 'i18n' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vuex-router-sync' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-bows' },
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-breakpoint-component', ssr: false }
  ],

  /*
  ** Modules
  */
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
    [
      '@nuxtjs/pwa',
      {
        icon: {
          sizes: iconSizes
        },
        // Override certain meta tags
        meta: {
          viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1',
          favicon: true // Generates only apple-touch-icon
        },
        manifest: {
          name: siteTitle,
          lang: config.env.DEFAULTLANG,
          dir: 'ltr',
          short_name: shortTitle,
          theme_color: themeColor,
          start_url: '/',
          display: 'standalone',
          background_color: '#fff',
          description: siteDescription
        }
      }
    ]
  ],

  /*
  ** Workbox config
  */
  workbox: {
    config: {
      debug: false,
      cacheId: siteTitle
    }
  },

  /*
  ** Axios config
  */
  axios: {
    baseURL: '/'
  },

  /*
  ** Generate
  */
  generate: {
    subFolders: true,
    routes: [
      ...generateRoutesFromData({
        langs: config.env.LANGS,
        postTypes: postTypes,
        dataPath: '../../../../../static/data',
        bundle: 'basic',
        homeSlug: config.env.HOMESLUG,
        errorPrefix: config.env.ERROR_PREFIX
      })
    ]
  },

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      /*
      ** Run ESLINT on save
      */
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  },

  /*
  ** Router
  */
  router: {
    linkActiveClass: 'is-active',
    linkExactActiveClass: 'is-active-exact',
    middleware: ['i18n'],
    extendRoutes(routes) {
      // extends basic routes (based on your files/folders in pages directory) with i18n locales (from our config.js)
      const newRoutes = generateLocalizedRoutes({
        baseRoutes: routes,
        defaultLang: config.env.DEFAULTLANG,
        langs: config.env.LANGS,
        routesAliases: config.routesAliases
      })

      // Clear array
      routes.splice(0, routes.length)

      // Push newly created routes
      routes.push(...newRoutes)
    }
  },

  /*
  ** Sitemap Configuration
  */
  sitemap: {
    path: '/sitemap.xml',
    hostname: config.env.FRONTENDURLPRODUCTION,
    cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 15,
    generate: true,
    routes: [
      ...generateRoutesFromData({
        langs: config.env.LANGS,
        postTypes: postTypes,
        dataPath: '../../../../../static/data',
        bundle: 'basic',
        homeSlug: config.env.HOMESLUG,
        errorPrefix: config.env.ERROR_PREFIX
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

You can see that the `generateLocalizedRoutes` and the `generateRoutesFromData` methods are used to generate localized routes and is also taking post json files to generate routes from data (`:slug`).

**--------- Edit 2:**
I got it to run eventually.
I had to require all parts within the nuxt.config.js instead of importing them. I also resolved issues with the certificates. So I thought it was all cool .

BUT!!! :
Then I found out that I had my config file used within my post template.
So I thought I would also require the file within my template:
Like `const config = require('~/config')`.
But then I would get this error:

> [nuxt] Error while initializing app TypeError: ""exports" is read-only"

After some research, I found that is probably a thing when using common.js require and module.exports together with ES6 import/export within my project. (Probably linked to: https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf/issues/1).

So how could I still use my config.js when running nuxt programmatically (with require) and then also within my app?

I am glad to hear any ideas on this...
Cheers

Comment: Show the whole `nuxt.config.js`

Comment: What nuxt version?

Comment: @Aldarund Newest nuxt version: 2.3.4

Comment: @Styx I edited my question and added my nuxt config

Comment: I also tried to add `dev: (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')` to my nuxt.config.js as indicated here, but no success: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-dev#the-dev-property

Comment: Instead of importing I required those parts. I now got the app running, but now I am facing problems with my certificate for localhost...
I will try it with a clean slate, using nuxt out of the box and then try to reverse-engineer things within my project... 

Comment: Your initial error was because you are using imports with `module.exports`.
Thats not correct. `module.exports`  should be `export default {` . Module.export is for when u use require.
As for new issue its not really clear what u trying to achieve

Comment: @Aldarund  No my initial error was that I tried to run a node app with a file `server.js`, which required my `nuxt.config.js` which used ES6 syntax and could not be understood.  But you are right normally using es6 it should be `export default`.
But if I run `node server.js` this must work with require & module.exports. 

I now have the solution that when I run nuxt programmatically I just have require only on my nuxt config. (So I had to change my config.js `export default` to `module.exports` to make it work with `require`. I have not found any solution how to import it later on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just to close this:
My problem resulted from running nuxt as a node app, which does not understand ES6 import statements, which appeared in my nuxt config.

So I had to rewrite things to work with commons.js (require).

This works for now.
(I also tried to run `babel-node` when starting the server.js, but had no success. Does not mean this did not work, I just wasn't keen on trying harder).

Thanks for the comments.
cheers